# Downsize -Xms improved GC time

Tags: java, memory, garbage-collection, websphere, heap-memory

We have an AIX-Websphere java7 server which uses a very large in-memory table/array object typically around 3,1 GB size. For this server we configured -Xms=3072m and -Xmx=3840m (GC algorithm=gencon). It was working OK until one day that suddenly increased the GC time from milliseconds to seconds every minute according to Dynatrace.

The huge object usually grows because there are few deletes, no update but a constant flow of inserts.

Trying different approaches we improved the GC time (again with milliseconds) just changing -Xms to 1024m.

Does anybody know what principle allows this improvement just donwsizing Xms? What I'd read in other post was the opposite. That is, that increasing Xms or even matching it to Xmx would be the optimal approach.

Comment: It is 64-bit JVM?

Comment: Yes.
java version "1.7.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap6470sr9fp30-20160112_01(SR9 FP30))
IBM J9 VM (build 2.6, JRE 1.7.0 AIX ppc64-64 Compressed References 20151222_283043 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR9_20151222_1626_B283043
JIT  - tr.r11_20151209_107111.01
GC   - R26_Java726_SR9_20151222_1626_B283043_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20151222_283043)
JCL - 20160112_01 based on Oracle jdk7u95-b13

Answer (score 1):

The long GC pauses are probably due to heap fragmentation requiring a compaction to place some object in the tenure region of the heap. If 3.1 GB of a max 3840m heap is occupied by the cache object, there is very little working space in the heap for the normal flow of object allocation and removal that occurs when Java programs execute. Since Java objects must be allocated in a contiguous memory space, if some object is allocated for which no sufficiently large contiguous space is available in the heap memory, a compaction is required. Compaction is a relatively long slow process of rearranging the location of objects in the heap to eliminate small spaces between objects and create a large contiguous area for new allocations (like defragmenting the hard drive on old Windows systems).

Frankly I'm rather surprised that a configuration such as you described would ever perform well. Besides the "cache object" mentioned (probably this is actually a collection of many small objects?) there will be a baseline set of long-lived objects which implement the WebSphere runtime, which require typically more than 100 MB. And then in any Java system, there is a constant flow of object creation and deletion (through garbage collection). A typical rule of thumb is to size the heap so that after a global GC the tenure area is 50% free - anything less than 20% free after a global will lead to undesirable GC overhead.

Do you have verbose GC logging enabled in this configuration? That is the only way to actually know what's going on inside the heap, and knowing that is essential to the health and performance of a Java system. We recommend enabling GC logging (by adding -verbose:gc to the JVM arguments) in all Java systems, in production as well as test environments. The overhead of GC logging in IBM Java is very low and the diagnostic value is very high.

As for why setting -Xms1024 improved performance there are several possibilities.

First it is possible that this change did not actually fix anything. You did not see long GC pauses for some time, then they appeared, now they have (at least temporarily) disappeared. Automatic memory management (of which GC is the cleanup part) is a probabilistic function, rather than deterministic, as object placement in the heap can change based on random variations such as objects being allocated in slightly different order. If I were operating the system, I would not trust the improvement without seeing GC logs that show that all is well.

Another possibility is that, if the cache size fluctuates a lot over time so that the heap fill varies a lot, then the heap may be growing and shrinking more with the small -Xms setting. When the heap shrinks a compaction is performed to move the live objects distributed through the large heap space into the new smaller space, so that the small heap will be in a contiguous memory address range. The heap shrinkage compactions would typically occur at times when the system is not very busy (that's why the heap is pretty empty) and there is less live data to deal with, so the compaction will be shorter and less likely to noticeably affect performance.

In general the best GC performance will be realized by setting -Xms and -Xmx the same, because then heap resizing does not occur at all. However, to know what the appropriate size is, you should enable GC logging and examine the log covering a week or more of operation. The heap should be sized so that at least 30% of the tenure space is free after a global GC, so that the time spent performing GC is not excessive.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to add verbose and examine it with GCMV trying to follow the 30% tenure row. On the other hand, I'm going to change the post to notice that the cache object is nos really a cache (I let myself carried away by the class name) but an in-memory array/table so it doesn't really change but to grow (there are a few deletes, no update but a constant flow of insertions)